# Python File Parsing

Tags: python, csv, file-io, export-to-csv

To set the context I have a directory with 200-300 files, each file ranges in size (# of lines). I pase the files and export them to a csv file. I think the last time I ran it the csv file had over 340,000 rows. On top of that the first 8 files are constantly being written to so I lose data while parsing sometimes.

Now, each file is set up like this:

```
DateTime Message Action ActionDetails
```

I have code in place to take go through all the files, parse them and then output to a csv file:

```
for infile in listing:
    _path2 = _path + infile
    f = open(_path2, 'r')
    labels = ['date', 'message', 'action', 'details']
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, labels, delimiter=' ', restkey='rest')

    for line in reader:
        if line.get('rest'):
            line['details'] += ' %s' % (' '.join(line['rest']))
        out_file.write(','.join([infile,line['date'], line['message'], line['action'], line['details']]) + '\n')

    f.close()
out_file.close()
```

I was wondering what the "best" way to go about copying the first 8 files so I don't lose data while parsing would be. By best I mean take the least amount of time as the total time to run the python script at the moment is about  35-45 seconds.

Comment: Would copying the file and parsing the copy be acceptable?

Comment: I have looked at such things as `shutil `but don't really know much about it to know if its what I want to use.

Comment: @thegrinner I don't see why not. The files will be deleted after parsing so yeah probably.

Comment: Are the first 8 files being written to the front or back of the file? Even if you make a copy with shutil it will likely be a portion of the file at best. If this is the case you might as well just read from the correct end of the file (unless it is constantly being overwritten). If you need the whole file you could put some logic in to see if the file is still growing while reading and only finish the read when it stops. It also depends on the box you are running. Unfortunately, any file copy operations on windows are not atomic so you might run into issues there.

Comment: @PaulSeeb The files are being overwritten. It looks like the first is overwritten, then seoncd, third, so on. and it all happens inside about a minute/minute and a half.

Comment: It looks like you are writting data into a new file. Does the order of that data matter?

Comment: Preferably yes, although there is a date time stamp on each line so I guess order doesn't have to play a huge role.

Comment: is this okay across files too? Looks like you are merging certain data from a whole bunch of CSV files?

Comment: Not across files no, I want the data from each file to be grouped together, preferably in the correct order via timestamp but as close as I can get if you have something else in mind. I only use one csv file as well. I am merging all the data from the text files into one csv file. The data from the text files is space delimited not comma as well, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a little bored. Try this on for size. I didn't actually have a chance to check if it was parsing and writting correctly but other than that I believe it should run given some info. This problem is a good opportunity to use queueing. Let me know how fast it runs!

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue
import os
import time
import sys

# declare some global items
# queue that an author thread can write line items to a csv
write_q = Queue.Queue()

# queue filled with files to parse 
read_q = Queue.Queue()

# queue filled with files that have size change during read. Can
# preload this queue to optimize however program should handle any
# file that changes during operation
moving_q = Queue.Queue()

# given csv labels
labels = ['date', 'message', 'action', 'details']

# global for writer thread so it knows when to close
files_to_parse = True

# parsing function for any number of threads
def file_parser():    
    # Each parser thread will run until the read_q is empty
    while True:
        moving = False
        # Test for a file from the read queue or moving queue 
        try:
            if not moving_q.empty():
                try:
                    f_path = moving_q.get(False)
                    moving = True
                # if the moving queue is empty after trying to read
                # might have been snatched by different thread. Ignore error
                except Queue.Empty:
                    pass
            else:
                # No items left in moving queue so grab non moving file
                f_path = read_q.get(False)
        # all files have been dealt with
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "Done Parsing"
            sys.exit()

        # Following will parse a file and test that the file is not being
        # modified during the read
        with open(f_path, 'r') as f:
            # csv reader setup
            reader = csv.DictReader(f, labels, delimiter=' ', restkey='rest')

            # initillized file size (when we started reading)
            pre = os.path.getsize(f_path)

            # store output items in a list so if file is updated during read
            # we can just ignore those items and read file later
            line_items = []

            # parse the file line by line
            for line in reader:
                # Check that file hasn't been updated
                post = os.path.getsize(f_path)
                if pre != post:
                    # if file has changed put the file back on the queue and clear the output lines
                    moving_q.put(f_path)
                    line_items = None
                    break
                # parse the line and add it to output list
                else:
                    if line.get('rest'):
                        line['details'] += ' %s' % (' '.join(line['rest']))
                        line_items.append(','.join([infile,line['date'], line['message'], line['action'], line['details']]) + '\n')

            # don't want to do reading and writing in same thread. Push
            # all line items onto the write thread for the author to deal with    
            if line_items and moving:
                write_q.put(line_items)
                moving_q.task_done()
            elif line_items and not moving:
                write_q.put(line_items)
                read_q.task_done()

# author thread that will write items to a file as other threads complete
# tasks. Should help speed up IO bound processing
def file_author(out_file):
    with open(out_file,'w') as f:
        # parse files until all the parser threads are running
        while files_to_parse or not read_q.empty():
            # only one writer thread so write as items are put into thread
            if not read_q.empty():
                line_items = write_q.get(False)
                for line_item in line_items:
                    f.write(line_item)
                write_q.task_done()
            # sleep in the downtime so we dont overload PC
            else:
                time.sleep(.1)
    print "Done writting"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # list of file names as you had before
    listing = []
    outfile = "MyNewCSVfile.csv"

    # You can optimize parsing by adding known "moving files" directly
    # to the moving_queue, however program should handle either way
    for infile in listing:
        _path2 = _path + infile
        write_q.put(_path2)

    # make a writer thread
    t = Thread(target = file_author, args = (outfile,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    # make some parse threads
    for i in range(10):
        t = Thread(target = file_parser)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    # wait for parser threads to finish work
    read_q.join()
    moving_q.join()

    # close author
    files_to_parse = False
    time.sleep(.1)
    print "Complete"
```

Comment: Ha, wasn't expecting such a large response. Thank you though. It seems to work fine, all the output looks correct. I over estimated the time mine took to run (about 20 seconds), your code runs in about 14-15.

Comment: Hope the comments helped you understand it. I got a little into it, it is a good problem.